# Pygame music switch (ON/OFF multiple songs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspbian

I'm really new to python so I don't have much experience. I'm creating a RPi program to play and stop 7 different songs using toggle switches (https://ktechnics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mini-6a-125vac-spdt-mts-102-3-pin-2-position-on-on-toggle-switch.jpg).

I'm using the PullUP/DOWN resistors of the GPIO pins for the switches and the pygame.mixer.music module to play the songs. It works as expected with one song:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pygame

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

cancion_1 = '/media/pi/PIERRE/0001.mp3'

while True:
    switch_1 = GPIO.input(18)

    if switch_1 == False:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            print("Cancion 1 Sonando")
            pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion_1)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

    else:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            print("Cancion 1 Callada")
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

But when I try to add more songs the program only plays the first song:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pygame

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

cancion_1 = '/media/pi/PIERRE/0001.mp3'
cancion_2 = '/media/pi/PIERRE/0002.mp3'

while True:
    switch_1 = GPIO.input(18)
    switch_2 = GPIO.input(19)

    if switch_1 == False:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            print("Cancion 1 Sonando")
            pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion_1)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

    elif switch_1 == True:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            print("Cancion 1 Callada")
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    elif switch_2 == False:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            print("Cancion 2 Sonando")
            pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion_2)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

    elif switch_2 == True:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            print("Cancion 2 Callada")
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

I tried creating a function for each song and calling it later but it doesn't work either. Any idea??

Comment: You need to rethink your logic. For example: if `switch_1 == False:` is true, none of the other `elif` blocks are entered. Even `if switch_2 == True:` for example. Also, do you want to play more than one song at a time?

Comment: No. I don't want to play more than one song at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your logic only allows the first song to be played. Because one of either the first condition (`if switch_1 == False:`) or the second (`elif switch_1 == True:`) will be true. Because of this, conditions 3 and 4 never get reached.

Here's one way to reconfigure:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pygame

# Create a list of tuples. First index is gpio pin, 2nd is song
# This marries the pin data with the song data
# It also allows you to easily add more pins/songs
song_data = [(18, "/media/pi/PIERRE/0001.mp3"),
             (19, "/media/pi/PIERRE/0002.mp3")]

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Use a loop to setup pins
for pin,_ in song_data:
   GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

# A function to check a pin and react
def check_toggle(pin, song):
    # Looks like you want to play when switch == False
    # I'm adding these variables to clarify
    button_is_pressed = not GPIO.input(pin)
    music_is_playing = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()
    if button_is_pressed and not music_is_playing:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    elif not button_is_pressed and music_is_playing:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

while True:
    for pin,song in song_data:
        check_toggle(pin, song)
    # You might want to add a sleep here to keep from hogging the CPU
```

Note: In this example, if you have both switches on, only the first song gets played. Pygame can only play one song at a time. Which makes toggle switches seem like a bad choice here. It is not clear what should happen when 2 toggles are both switched on. Consider using [momentary switches](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=momentary%20switch) or a [rotary switch](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=rotary%20switch).